Python venv not finding module that exists
Brand new out of the box ubuntu 24.04 with python 3.12.3. I'm trying to port over an app but python is not finding the modules in the virtual environment. The VE is set up in directory ./venv and activated, and pip list shows cherrypy is present:
(venv) $ pip list
Package            Version
------------------ -----------
...
CherryPy           18.10.0
...
(venv) $ 

but it is not found:
(venv) $ python
Python 3.12.3 (main, Apr 10 2024, 05:33:47) [GCC 13.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cherrypy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cherrypy'
>>> import CherryPy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CherryPy'
>>> 
(venv) $ 

The files do exist in the venv tree:
(venv) $ ls -ld venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/cherrypy/
drwxrwxr-x 8 russell russell 4096 Jul 29 09:02 venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/cherrypy/
(venv) $ 

None of the other modules listed by pip list can be imported either. This is the first time I've used python VEs (upgraded system makes it difficult not to) so I may be overlooking something obvious. I have looked around and found the same question for example, here but none of the suggestions helped.

Try checking your $PATH variable (echo $PATH). The path to your virtualEnv should be at first place. Also try whereis command both for python and pip (whereis pip, whereis python). Both should show the path to you virtualEnv/bin. (Not necessarily at the first place now)

Thank you - it wasn't PATH but it was a wrong python image. I had bash functions defined for python and python3 on my old machine because python messed up the stty settings, so the functions called stty afterwards to fix up the terminal. So, I was getting the absolute path from those functions rather than the venv image needed. Thanks, this solved it.

I was using the wrong python image because of shell functions that referenced the system image rather than the venv image. After unsetting the shell functions import works properly in the venv.
